# MS SQL Page split confusion

Tags: sql-server, index, fill-factor, page-splits

I am a bit confused about page splits in MS SQL and I'm looking for a definitive answer. There seem to be two versions of the story:

1 - Fillfactor only affects how full pages are at the time the index is created/rebuilt. Page splits are always 50/50

2 - Fillfactor also affects how pages are split. So if there is 70% fillfactor and a page overflows, it will split 70/30

Thanks a lot

Comment: The documentation supports version 1 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx), which states approximately half the rows are moved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> FILLFACTOR =fillfactor
>   Applies to: SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2016, SQL Database V12.
>
> Specifies a percentage that indicates how full the Database Engine should make the leaf level of each index page **during index creation or rebuild**. fillfactor must be an integer value from 1 to 100. If fillfactor is 100, the Database Engine creates indexes with leaf pages filled to capacity.
>
> The FILLFACTOR setting applies **only when the index is created or rebuilt**. The Database Engine **does not dynamically keep the specified percentage** of empty space in the pages. To view the fill factor setting, use the sys.indexes catalog view.

Fill factor applies to the leaf pages. [PAD_INDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) will determine what happens to non-leaf pages. From the same BoL page:

> PAD_INDEX = { ON | OFF }
>
> ON
>    The percentage of free space that is specified by fillfactor is applied to the intermediate-level pages of the index.
>
> OFF or fillfactor is not specified
>    The intermediate-level pages are filled to near capacity

Page splitting can occur at all levels of the BTree, including the root level. Due to fan-out, however, the frequency at which intermediate pages split is (typically) an order of magnitude less than that at which leaves split. Also there are many fewer non-leaf pages than leaf pages. Consequently PAD_INDEX is less concerning than FILLFACTOR. Still worth thinking about, especially on randomly-inserted indexes.

During writes, pages will be filled up to 100%. Then they will split 50/50, or as close as possible to ensure each row is contained entirely on a single page. I believe the split is always 50/50. Subsequent writes may be skewed, however, so one of the new pages fills much quicker than the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess there could be situations in real life where the split is nowhere near 50/50. One clarification please: does that really apply to the leaf pages only? I thought page splitting also concerns intermediate levels and fillfactor applies to them as well.

Comment: @Mashchax Page splits may not always be 50/50, they can be jagged. Fill factor only applies to leaf pages as Michael has said.

Comment: Great explanation, particularly the clarification that it applies only on index creation / rebuilding; that was something easy to miss

Comment: @SeanGallardy In what circumstances would the split not be even? Any external links you're able to share?

Comment: @MichaelGreen "It depends" :) and no, not publically documented.